# How multiple matches in a string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the same block in regex pattern multiple times in a string, but doesn't work.
This is the pattern :

```
^(--move|--take)?\s{1}((-f|-o|-d)?\s{1}\".*\")\s+
```

And it might be match this type of things

```
--move -o D:\blabla.txt -d F:\rr.txt
```

Comment: Your input doesn't have quotes

Comment: Do you mean `-{1}-{1}m{1}o{1}v{1}e{1}`?  (Just kidding.)

Comment: Also adding them still not work, don't capture another path

Comment: I think I should use the anchor \G for match more times the arguments, now take all the output but in one result instead one by one.

Comment: Without more details (language/tool used, more test cases with sample input and expected output), it is difficult to help, but I will suggest [`(?:(--move|--take)?\s+|(?!^)\G)\s*((-[fod])?\s+(\"[^\"]*\"|\S+))`](https://regex101.com/r/nM4cX4/1).